# Operador and Ruby

Tags: ruby

Gostaria que esse código pegasse dois números e mostrasse os números divisíveis pelo primeiro,pelo segundo e pelos dois. Porém não consegui fazer o uso corrento do AND para este caso, pois o array div_pelos2 volta vazio.

```
def self.divisiveis(num1, num2)
    div_num1 = Array.new
    div_num2 = Array.new
    div_pelos2 = Array.new

    for i in 1..49
        i += 1
        if i % num1 == 0
            div_num1.push (i)
        elsif i % num2 == 0
            div_num2.push (i)
        elsif (i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 == 0) 
            div_pelos2.push (i)
        end
    end

    return div_pelos2, div_num1, div_num2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu && está correto, o problema está no elsif. Repare nesse trecho:

```
 elsif (i % num1 == 0) && (i % num2 == 0)
```

"elsif" é o mesmo que "else if", por isso, esse trecho de código só é executado caso a condição falhe nos outros 2 cenários anteriores, que testam exatamente se o número é divisível por um ou por outro.

troque por `if ... end`

Comment: Se há a possibilidade de `num1` e `num2` forem múltiplos um do outro (que eu creio que haja), então a existência de qualquer `elsif` será um erro de lógica. Eu trocaria os dois `elsif`s existentes de acordo com essa recomendação do @OrlandoCorrea